# Manage Time in Subscription Purchase - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

For my app, I want to provide Subscription based In App Purchase feature.
So I have created a product at Apple Store - **Non-Renewing Subscription**.

But in that product creation, I didn't specify any time up to which time this subscription remain valid, for ex. Monthly or Weekly Subscription days limit.

So from app I can manage Subscription purchase related thing but how to get information about expiry of Subscription? So that I can show again Subscription dialog to make purchase again.

Whether Apple take care about activeness of Subscription product or its our responsibility to manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Auto-Renewable Subscription in Non-Renewing Subscription you need to handle the duration your self in the app.
See this tutorial, espicially the part under 'Overview'  - https://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial

Regarding managing the subscription:
Your app needs to handle that.
For supporting cases users delete and re-install your application, you have two options:

1. Save the purchase data as part of the user account detail in your application server. When the user logs in to the app after re-installing it he will back his progress along with his purchases.
2. Another option: after installing the app use restore purchases: `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];` There is an example under 'Restoring a Subscription' in the above link.

I recommend you to go over [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html) on subscription based purchases.

Comment: thanks for you quick reply. Basically I have created Non-Renewing Subscription - project just few mins ago but I can't able to find any place for setting time duration for that.

Comment: If I store purchase Date field based on receipt and after few days user by mistake delete the app then how to again provide subscription facility to this same user?

Comment: You don't see the duration section in the iap? Take a look at this screenshot to see where it should be - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Art/Understanding_Subscription_Groups4_2x.png

Comment: If the user deleted the app, you can:
1. Save the receipt data as part of the user account detail in your application server. When the user logs in to the app after re-installing it he will back his progress along with his purchases.
2. Another option: after installing the app use restore purchases:
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, it is not possible to format in comments. Would you like to update the original question and I will update the answer? Or open another question

Comment: I have this kind of view at Apple Store when I try to add "Non-Renewing Subscription" - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6CFlS0aZDPiMjNWNVRmZGhyQWM

Comment: Whether second option work for me - "after installing the app use restore purchases" ? If I don't have registration process within my app. I hope restore transaction only possible within actual valid activation period.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132629/discussion-between-little-and-siddharth).

Comment: I written over chatting section so when you become available please message me.